# Removing the last octet of IP using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ip

How can I remove the last octet of an IP in SQL Server 2014 in a `SELECT` query?

- Input: `10.123.456.789`
- Desired output: `10.123.456`

Thanks in advance

Comment: try 
SELECT LEFT('10.123.456.789', LEN('10.123.456.789') - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE ('10.123.456.789')))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `LEFT()`  , `CHARINDEX()` , `LEN()` and `REVERSE()` :

```
SELECT LEFT(t.column,LEN(t.column) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(t.column)))
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT PARSENAME([ClientIp],4) + '.' + PARSENAME([ClientIp],3) + '.' + PARSENAME([ClientIp],2) + '.0' FROM T;`

[Documentation for TSQL PARSENAME()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(TRY_PARSE_TSQL);k(sql13.swb.tsqlresults.f1);k(sql13.swb.tsqlquery.f1);k(MiscellaneousFilesProject);k(DevLang-TSQL)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=sql-server-ver15)